# Control flow within an eval function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, eval, continue

If I include a `continue` as a parameter of an `eval()` instruction, it does not work as expected. For example, when executing the following code:

```
listParam = {'a','b','c'};
a = 17;
b = NaN;
c = 4;

for ii=1:numel(listParam),
    eval(['if isnan(',listParam{ii},'), continue; end']);
    disp(['The parameter ', listParam{ii}, ' is not a NaN.']);
end
```

It will prompt the error:

```
Error: A CONTINUE may only be used within a FOR or WHILE loop.
```

Anybody knows why?

Note: I know that I should avoid `eval()` and the previous example could be refactored in a much better coding; but I found a weird behaviour and I am curious what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

The expression you pass to `eval` must be a valid matlab expression on it's own, any surrounding code is not considered. This means each `continue` must be surrounded by a loop. Either put the surrounding `for` within your eval or put the `continue` outside.

Comment: +1 Any reference about the fact that the argument to `eval` is evaluated independent of "normal" code?

Comment: I updated my answer to precise it. @LuisMendo: I don't have any reference, but to my understanding the code is simply not a valid expression.

Comment: @LuisMendo Concerning the scope of `eval`, I took some simple experiments; if one puts `continue` in a separate `foo.m` script (with a single line saying `continue`), and in main script uses `eval('foo')`, the `for` loop will get controlled.

Comment: @Yvon That's interesting!

Answer (score 2):

As @Daniel has pointed out, `eval` is called by the script, while it is not directly controlled by the `for` loop. You can think it as: the `continue` in `eval` would move the program counter to the head of the code inside `eval`, but not that of the `for` loop; this of course would fail, as Matlab does not allow jumping between lines.

A `continue` can only appear directly inside a `for` or `while` loop. However, you can hack the code like this:

```
for ii=1:numel(listParam),
    eval(['if isnan(',listParam{ii},'), x=1; else, x=0; end']);
    if x
        continue;
    end
    disp(['The parameter ', listParam{ii}, ' is not a NaN.']);
end
```

Strangely, `x` happens to appear in the script's stack. However, this is far from a good piece of code. Never use this method.

---

Edit: about the "control" scope of `eval`.

I'm not talking about the variable scope / workspace of `eval`. Hints can be found in several documentations like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7kmd5). In short, `eval` uses the "current" workspace.

However, I found the following things interesting:

1. Running `continue` directly in `eval`

   ```
   for ii = 1:2
       eval('continue')
       ii+10
   end
   ```

   This simply fails, as shown in the question. The error is `Error: A CONTINUE may only be used within a FOR or WHILE loop.` which means the `continue` inside `eval` cannot find any loop (the `for` loop).
2. Calling a separate script in a `for` loop

   ```
   for ii = 1:2
       foo
       ii+10
   end
   ```

   while script `foo.m` is

   ```
   ii
   continue
   ```

   First of all, in `foo.m` Mlint gives a red-line warning, which usually indicates an error that can stop the code from running, saying that `CONTINUE is only valid in a FOR or WHILE loop`. But pressing F5 on `foo.m` does not have any problem - in fact running a single `continue` anywhere does not crash the code.

   Running the main script gives output

   ```
   ii =
        1
   ii =
        2
   >>
   ```

   ....so `foo.m` catches the `for` loop?
3. `eval('foo')` - I really don't understand Matlab

   ```
   for ii = 1:2
       eval('foo')
       ii+10
   end
   ```

   The result surprised me a bit.

   ```
   ii =
        1
   ans =
       11
   ii =
        2
   ans =
       12
   >>
   ```

Thought: `eval` runs the code in an independent *control flow*, but shares its workspace with the current one. It is (something but not exactly) like an [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#videos) model, in which (here in Matlab) different pieces of code can interact with the same set of variables, but cannot interact with each other in the sense of control flow.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find any existing resources as reference to prove this idea.

This does not change my solution: in any case, try to avoid using `eval`.